# Looking for a template-based C++ library that solves linear programs

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I'm looking for a LP (Linear Program) solver,  that uses Simplex algorithm or anything it likes. I have an additional request, that the solver will carry out all its compuations without any loss of precision !!

So if I can find a template-based C++ library, that let me define the underline type of the numerical variables it uses, I will let it use the boost's type cpp_ratinal, and thus all computations won't loss any precision due to rounding of floating-points.

Does such C++ library exists ?

Comment: You mean cpp_rational?

Answer (score 0):

Both SoPlex and QSOpt have exact simplex solvers.  They will perform better than what you propose to do.  I should warn you, however, that SoPlex's exact simplex solver doesn't actually work; it's fairly straightforward to construct a feasible linear program with rational data on which SoPlex reports infeasibility.

Using exact arithmetic for the whole of the solving process is not a good idea.  You wind up having to row-reduce big matrices in exact arithmetic, and the exact numbers involved grow huge.  I believe GLPK's exact solver run simplex in rational arithmetic; you might play with it and see how much you like its performance.

Among interior-point solvers, SDPA-GMP is an interior-point method for a generalisation of linear programming that uses arbitrary-precision arithmetic.  You have to decide on the precision you want to use, but you might be able to use SDPA-GMP to get a very high-precision solution, then do some sort of high-precision crossover to get an exact optimal solution.  (I've never tried this since I've never wanted to solve an LP exactly.)  I would suspect the simplex-based solvers would run faster than an IPM in this case, too.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at SoPlex:

http://soplex.zib.de

SoPlex uses a technique called "iterative refinement" to increase the solution quality to arbitrary precision. All simplex operations are performed in double precision arithmetic to get a near optimal solution in a short time. Afterwards very few pivots are performed on a slightly modified (error reducing)  LP to determine the exact solution. 
It uses GMP, the Gnu multiple precision library in a template fashion - you may be able to use cpp_rational as well, if you don't like GMP. 
In the current release version the LU factorization is not yet available in exact arithmetic, so you don't get an exact proof of optimality. This is already implemented in our developer version, though and will be released by the end of the year.

http://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/solrsearch/index/search/searchtype/collection/id/16090/start/0/rows/10/subjectfq/Exact+linear+programming

Comment: I *think* QSOpt has an option to do something similar, too.

Comment: Also, how does SoPlex handle the case where the wheels completely fall off---where the basis factorisation is of no help whatsoever in solving equations whose left-hand side is the basis?  It seems that iterative refinement cannot help you there.

Comment: What do you mean by the basis being the left-hand side? If the factorization is done in rational arithmetic and the basis matrix is truly nonsingular then it is possible to solve the system of linear equations - no matter how the the left-( or right-) hand side looks like. It may still happen that the simplex algorithm crashes since there are still many operations that rely on floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I thought you used floating-point, then double-double, then quad-double, then MPFR, only doing an exact factorisation at the very end?  Sort of like geometry code does; do everything in floating-point and only increase precision when you aren't sure how a predicate should evaluate.

Comment: No, SoPlex is switching between double precision (for speed) and rational arithmetic (for exactness). We need exact error computations for the iterative refinement procedure. The exact factorization is indeed only performed at the very end. As far as I know, Qsopt_exact is doing what you describe - increase precision whenever necessary.

Comment: Gotcha.  So you use a floating-point factorisation, but you compute matrix-vector products in rational arithmetic so you can do IR with the floating-point factorisation?  Do you compute a rational factorisation if the norm of the residual isn't going down fast enough in IR or something?

Comment: Currently, the factorization is only done in rational arithmetic to compute the final solution vectors of the optimal basis. A fallback mechanism to GMP during the solving process in case of numerical difficulties is an obvious improvement but not (yet) implemented. It may also slow down the simplex quite dramatically - still better than no solution, though.

Comment: SoPlex appears to report "infeasible" for problems with feasible solutions, even when asked to use rational arithmetic.  Then it returns a Farkas certificate that is not a Farkas certificate.  I do not believe your rational LP solver can solve rational LPs.

Comment: How do you "tell" SoPlex to use rational arithmetic? Simply compiling with GMP is not sufficient, you also need to set the tolerances to very small values (10^-30) to make sure that the iterative refinement process kicks in. Could you send me your test instance, please?

Comment: I set SOLVEMODE to RATIONAL and SYNCMODE to AUTO and OPTTOL, FEASTOL, EPSILON_ZERO, EPSILON_FACTORIZATION, EPSILON_UPDATE, and EPSILON_PIVOT to 1e-300.  Upping them to 1e-30 has no perceptible effect.  Neither does leaving the EPSILON_ settings alone.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/EZSAdE8T) is an example of a problem Soplex cannot solve, though it is feasible.

Comment: Thank you for the example problem. This really helps in further developing SoPlex and fixing bugs!

Comment: If you're going to get SoPlex to work on horrible instances like this, I, and probably some other people, will be very happy.  (Notice that `A` here is either a Vandermonde matrix or very close to it.)  It doesn't look like there is a publicly-released LP solver that works, is fast, and is actively maintained.  PPL's tableau simplex code and GLPK appear to be the only existing options if you want to drop the "is fast" requirement.